# [rmf_demo] How to generate the "0.yaml" file

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In our attempt to try out the rmf_demo examples, there is a file specified as "**0.yaml**" in magni_adapter.launch.xml, which is located at /install/rmf_demo_maps/share/rmf_demo_maps/maps/office/nav_graphs/0.yaml.

The file seems to be the equivalent lanes and vertices generated from traffic_editor but in gazebo's world coordinate.

Vertices in this **0.yaml** file are in meter while the coordinate of vertices in building.yaml file of traffic_editor are in pixels.

For example, coordinate of the same vertex in different files:

[office.world - magni1] : (11.553368836072618 -11.315970962255989)

[office.building.yaml - magni1_charger] : (1364.76, 1336.717)

[0.yaml - magni1_charger] : (11.553368836072618, -11.315970962255989)

Is there a conversion or any specific steps to obtain this **0.yaml**?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344334/%5Brmf_demo%5D-how-to-generate-the-%220.yaml%22-file/) by [webvenky](https://answers.ros.org/users/22361/webvenky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 117 on 2020-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The navigation graph yaml files are generated and installed to `rmf_demo_maps/share/` during build time. See [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/osrf/rmf_demos/blob/6c13ec56d66f9ccfa77ed121853de1e5a8e37da2/rmf_demo_maps/CMakeLists.txt#L41)  file within the `rmf_demo_maps` pkg. This is achieved using the `building_map_nav` tool from the `building_map_tools` pkg in the [osrf/traffic_editor](https://github.com/osrf/traffic_editor)  repository. The [source code](https://github.com/osrf/traffic_editor/blob/master/building_map_tools/building_map_generators/building_map_nav.py) should provide clarity on the transformations performed.

You may also generate the nav graphs by running

`ros2 run building_map_tools building_map_nav <input.yaml> <output directory>`

from a terminal after sourcing the workspace where `building_map_tools` was built.

---

Originally posted by [Yadunund](https://answers.ros.org/users/52033/yadunund/) with karma: 51 on 2020-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1